# Yammer API - Posting to External Networks

Tags: rest, cookies, oauth, yammer

I've used the Yammer API extensively for accessing current users internal network. All API calls have been working correctly (GET's and POST's) with the original token extracted from;

"https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id={App ID}&client_secret={App Secret}&code={Access Code}"

and using the headers; "Authorization : Bearer {Token}" and "Cookie : {Cookies Received from HTML request}.

I've gotten the tokens for all accessible networks using;
"https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json".

Accessing external networks beyond this point has proved troublesome. I changed the header to "Authorization : Bearer {NetworkToken}". While I am able to GET details from external networks, I cannot POST to external networks. I always receive a '401 Unauthorized' response. The 'Unauthorized' requests include deleting messages and liking messages in external networks.

Is there another step between being able to read data from an external network and enabling POST methods?

If I could get any insight into this i'd be extremely grateful!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered quite a few <strike>inconsistencies</strike> quirks with the Yammer API. I've figured out external networks in their totality now. Here are some things that may not be clear;

When doing a POST or DELETE request, do not include the network_permalink in the url! Only include the network_permalink when you're doing a GET request. This was my main issue.

Required request headers;

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept : application/json
Cookie : _workfeed_session_id=(A code that can be extracted from the response from your first request with an auth token)
Authorization : Bearer (Access token for whichever network you wish to access)
```

Oh and just FYI, to request threads within the 'All Company' group this is the url; https://www.yammer.com/(network_permalink)/api/v1/messages/general.json

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

When accessing external networks, you need to set the authToken to the authToken for that external network.

Step 1 - Get all auth tokens:

```
  yam.platform.request({
        url: "oauth/tokens.json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (msg) {
            accessTokens = msg;
           /....

        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            error(msg);
        }
```

Step 2: Set the authToken to the correct external network

```
var currentToken = "";
    $.each(accessTokens, function (i,val) {
        if (val.network_permalink == $.cookie('networkPermalink')) {
            currentToken = val;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks; I already have the auth tokens. As i'm not using an SDK this isn't something I can use directly. I should have mentioned I'm using C# to construct headers within a dictionary that i'm adding to the web request. I'm unsure where the 'networkPermalink' should be inserted apart from within the URL as described in the documentation; www.yammer.com/{NetworkPermalink}/{ResourcePath}

I have already tried inserting the individual network token within the header "Authorization : {NetworkToken}".

Comment: NetworkPermalink is only needed in the URL.  If you have the right token granted for External Network as Peter describe above and use the "Authorization: Bearer {NetworkToken}", it should work.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So i have already tried this (as stated in my question) and a few alternative combinations. Regardless I keep receiving a response of '401 Unauthorized' and the response header; WWW-AUTHENTICATE : Bearer realm="www.yammer.com"
Along with some irrelevant headers.

Can we move toward a solution to this? It's clearly not working as it should be. Perhaps this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

While I was working on a project last month, I used the following way to post message.

The message has to be Byte encrypted in UTF-8 format.
Specify the content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

So, an example code would be:

```
HttpWebRequest a = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
a.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + authToken);
a.Method = "POST";
byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("body=" + message + "&replied_to_id=" + threadID);
        a.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        a.ContentLength = message.Length;
        using (var postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var postStreamForResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader postReader = new StreamReader(postStreamForResponse);
            string results = postReader.ReadToEnd();
            postReader.Close();
        }
```